# setenv from awk in tcsh

Tags: awk, tcsh

I am trying to set environment variables one per line from awk:

```
$ <source command> awk '/inst/ { n = split($0,a,"/"); cmd = "setenv " a[n-1] "_ver" $0; system(cmd) }'
```

However the out I get is "sh: setenv: command not found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setenv` is a csh-only command, but `system()` runs its arguments through the Bourne shell (`/bin/sh`), not `csh`. You'd want to command to be `export VARIABLE=value` for Bourne shell.

However, even if you do that, it will be ineffective. `system()` starts a new shell and runs the command in that shell. As soon as the command terminates, that shell — and its environment — disappear. So the environment variable you set promptly disappears.

What you need to do is use `awk` to generate a list of `csh` commands to run and output then (don't try to run them). Then you need to make the shell that called `awk` read `awk`'s output and run it:

```
eval `the awk command`
```

Comment: Thanks. Should this work for multiple `awk` output lines?

Comment: It says "setenv: Too many arguments." even though the print output looks correct, one command per line.

Comment: Backtick command substitution probably collapses the output all into one line. Perhaps you need to separate the `setenv` commands with `;`.